# Unable to install RJAVA in a Ubuntu container

Tags: r, ubuntu, containers, rjava

I´m trying to install the library RJAVA in a Ubuntu container with R, Python and Jupyter installed.

I have installed jdk and this is the information that I get when I do:
`sudo R CMD javareconf`

```
root@071867e6c536:~# sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
Java version     : 10.0.2
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
Java headers gen.:
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux     -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-AitvI6/r-base-3.4.4=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

But, when I use install.packages("rJava") in Jupyter, I got this error:

```
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/R/lib’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message in install.packages("rJava"):
“installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status”
```

Anyone can tell me how can I do to install the library?

Comment: The `“installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status”` is given any time there's an installation error. That's the uninformative part of the output. What came *before* that?

Comment: I just only follow this tutorial --> https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rjava-on-ubuntu/ to install the rjava library. In the last step, I got the error " had non-zero exit status”".

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is that there is output after `install.packages("rJava")` and before `“installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status”` that will tell you more about **why** you get the error.

Comment: No, this is only what I get: https://imgur.com/mj6nEx5.

Comment: Hmm, I guess `Jupyter` (which I don't have much experience with) suppresses some output. That's kind of unfortunate. In this sort of (low information) situation, what I'd suggest first is to try installing the binary package to see if that works: `sudo apt install r-cran-rjava` (from the command line, not from R)

Comment: Yes, I did it and I got this:
root@071867e6c536:~# sudo apt install r-cran-rjava
r-cran-rjava is already the newest version (0.9-9-1ubuntu2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libapr1 libaprutil1 libcurl3-nss libcurl4-nss-dev libevent-2.1-6 libevent-core-2.1-6 libevent-dev libevent-extra-2.1-6 libevent-openssl-2.1-6
  libevent-pthreads-2.1-6 libserf-1-1 libssl1.0.0 libsvn1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 77 not upgraded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188349/discussion-between-duckmayr-and-alberto-aguilera).